# Call Api with slashed parameter "/"

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

so I build a service that call GET request
here's how I call it

```
async getAssetDetail(id: string) {
    let response = await Axios.get('/api/v1/asset/'+ id);
    this.assetDetail = response.data;
}
```

the problem is, my parameter `id` has value something like `2000/ABC/123`
so, the route will become `/api/v1/asset/2000/ABC/123` which resulting error 404

i already tried using string replace, but somehow it only replace the first slash

my API is build on C#

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<AssetDetailModel> GetAsset(string id)
    {
        var asset = await this.assetService.GetAssetDetail(id);
        return asset;
    }
```

i also tried to hardcode my api url to `2000%2FABC%2F123` and it's still getting same error

How to pass my parameter from service in typescript to api in C#? 
can anybody know the solution? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the slashes in the `id`, a *catch-all* route parameter would need to be used to grab everything after the route template.

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class AssetController: Controller {

    //GET /api/v1/asset/2000/ABC/123
    [HttpGet("{*id}")]
    public async Task<AssetDetailModel> GetAsset(string id) {
        var asset = await this.assetService.GetAssetDetail(id);
        return asset;
    }

}
```

In the above example, for the request `/api/v1/asset/2000/ABC/123`, the `id` would be assigned `2000/ABC/123`.

However, note that it will also take any query string values if included in the request.

```
/api/v1/asset/2000/ABC/123?param1=value1
```

would result in the `id` being assigned

```
2000/ABC/123?param1=value1
```

That means that the parameter should be validated in the action before being used.

For example

```
[HttpGet("{*id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<AssetDetailModel>> GetAsset(string id) {
    if(id == null || (id != null && id.IndexOf("?") > -1))
        return BadRequest();

    var asset = await this.assetService.GetAssetDetail(id);
    return asset;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the catch all route parameter will catch query string parameters. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @J.Loscos Check the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing `catch-all route parameters like {*article} can be used to capture the remaining portion of the URL path` which would also include query string

Comment: I can't do a test to check it right now but I would have thought that it would only catch the path and not the query

Comment: @J.Loscos here is another one from docs about the routing and the use of the catch-all https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slashes as %2F.

Comment: have you try this : 
axios.get('/api/v1/asset/', {
    params: {
      ID: '2000/ABC/123'
    }
  })